# Mark Git repository as local only so it can not be pushed?

Tags: git, github, push

I have a particular project that I never want to push to GitHub.  That is, I only want to use locally with Git and make sure it is never pushed to a remote repository.  Is there a way to mark a directory/project so that it is *locked down* and the *push* command will fail if tried?  That way I don't have to worry about accidentally pushing it.  I've been using Git for so long doing add/commit/push is rooted in my fingers and I don't want to have an *accident* during some late night programming session.

Comment: Is it for a specific folder/file or the entire project?

Comment: Yeah, it got me thinking too - repeating after KarthikRP - by "project" do you mean you want to prevent whole repository from being ever pushed? or just for some part of it, like prevent publishing of specific branches? or like making sure that some ignored files will not be accidentally added?

Comment: If the repository configuration doesn't contain any definitions for a remote repository, then `git push` won't do anything, because it doesn't have any place to actually push to...

Comment: Or you can track a local remote, so that when you push accidentally (and i think you will) it will be only pushed to some folder in your local machine.

Comment: @Acemad Interesting idea.  How do you set up a local remote?

Comment: @RobertOschler please take a look at my answer.

Comment: What is wrong with what @twalberg said?  I don't see the need to have a solution that does more work than is required.  What's the purpose of copying changes to a useless repo?

Comment: If you still want to be able to fetch and merge-and/or-rebase, so that you need to have a remote set at all, you can split it: give it a regular url and a separate `pushurl`.  Make the `pushurl` something that is harmless (local) or fails, as appropriate.

Comment: Since the add/commit/push is rooted in the OP's fingers, he'll surely do a push or two, and when he does, i think he just want to say "oh well, it won't go public anyways" and move on. But if there was no configured remote, git will show an error message and how to add a remote which could be distracting for the OP. I just think he WANTS to push, but not to a public repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a `pre-push` hook to prevent the repository from being pushed. Rename the existing `.git/hooks/pre-push.sample` to `.git/hooks/pre-push` (or create that file if it does not exist). The contents of the file should be something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo 'Repository cannot be pushed' 2>&1
exit 1
```

The `echo` is optional but the script should exit non-0.

Answer (score 4):

Two choices (that I know of):

1) Remove the local repository's reference to the remote repository.

```
git remote remove origin
```

Typically, there is only one remote reference that is named 'origin'.
   You can check for addiitonal references:

```
git remote show
```

2)  Keep the references, but point them to different repositories:

```
git remote set-url origin ${somethingElse}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a local remote as follows :

1) Create a bare repository somewhere in your machine using the following:

```
git init --bare path/to/localrem.git
```

This will create a bare repository without a working directory, this is what's typically used in actual remotes. (it'll create a folder called `localrem.git` which is the usual .git repo but this is for remotes, well obviously you can change `localrem` for any name you like)

2) Next in your original repository you add the new remote, as you would add any ordinary remote, except the path isn't a url :

```
git remote add origin path/to/localrem.git
```

3) Now you can push as you see fit without having to worry about the world seeing your work.

```
git push origin master
```

Of course that depends on which branch you would like to keep in your local remote.